# Detect Capital Letter in string package

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am a newbie and trying to detect the Letter C OR C/ OR C, in a string variable

```
x <- c("C", "C/", "C,", "C++", "C#", "Captain")
```

Desired output

```
True, True, True, False, False, False
```

Tried this but all capital letters are selected, excluding "Captain"

```
str_detect(x, "[C]")
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What about `x == 'C' | x == 'C/'` or `x %in% c('C', 'C/')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `grepl`:

```
grepl("(^| )C[/,]?( |$)", input)
[1] "The C programming language"  "The C/ programming language"
[3] "The C, programming language"
```

**Data:**

```
input <- c("The C programming language",
    "The C/ programming language",
    "The C, programming language",
    "The C++ programming language",
    "The C# programming language",
    "Captain of all")
```

### Demo

**Edit:**

Based on your updated expected output, maybe this is what you want:

```
grepl("^C[/,]?$", x)
```

Comment: Based on the updated example in OP's code, may be `grepl("^C[/,]*$", x)`

Comment: @akrun Right on.  But I actually like my version better.

Comment: yes, but it would give FALSE to third entry of the OP's example

Answer (score 1):

thanks to you both. This code finally worked for me:

```
str_detect(input, "(^| )C[/,]?( |/|$)")
```